# OpenGL camera direction

Tags: c++, c, opengl, camera

So I was reading [this](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/04-cameras-vectors-and-input/) tutorial's "Inverting the Camera Orientation Matrix" section and I don't understand why, when calculating the camera's up direction, I need to multiply the **inverse** of *orientation* by the up direction vector, and not just *orientation*.

I drew the following image to illustrate my insight of the tutorial I read.
What did I get wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, that tutorial explicitely states:

> The way we calculate the up direction of the camera is by taking the
>   "directly upwards" unit vector (0,1,0) and "unrotate" it by using the
>   inverse of the camera's orientation matrix. Or, to explain it
>   differently, the up direction is always (0,1,0) after the camera
>   rotation has been applied, so we multiply (0,1,0) by the inverse
>   rotation, which gives us the up direction before the camera rotation
>   was applied.

The up direction which is calculated here is the up direction *in world space*. In *eye space*, the up vector is `(0,1,0)` (by convention, one could define it differently). As the view matrix will transform coordinates from world space to eye space, we need to use the inverse to transform that up vector from eye space to the world space. Your image is wrong as it does not correctly relate to eye and world space.

Comment: Sorry, this still haunts me.
here's an example code. http://pastebin.com/nLL0uNgK
The camera only changes its horizontal angle, so the up direction of the camera shouldn't change. Then why is the final vector (0,0.86,-0.5) and not (0,1,0)?

Comment: @Pilpel: if you rotate _around_ x, your up vector will of course change. You have to rotate around _y_ for a horizontal rotation.